# How can I use peer-valid option with react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

So this is my component code. It can be used like this version 1. It perfectly works.
But I wanna use it with react-hook-form. When I use it like version 2, it doesn't work like before.
 It is always peer-valid state. I think bc {...props} is not empty, that's why..?

 Please help me. How can I use it?

- component code :

```
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { InputLabelProps } from "@/types/Forms";

export default function InputLabel ({ className, type, label, ...props }: InputLabelProps) {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  return (
    <div className="relative pt-2">
      <input
        type={type}
        className={cn(
          "peer flex h-10 w-full rounded-md border border-input bg-background px-3 py-2 text-sm ring-offset-background focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50",
          className,
        )}
        ref={inputRef}
        {...props}
      />
      {label && (
        <label
          htmlFor={props.id}
          className={`absolute font-semibold bg-background text-gray-400 rounded-md transition ease-in-out left-2 top-4 px-1 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-x-2 peer-focus:-translate-y-6 peer-valid:scale-75 peer-valid:-translate-x-2 peer-valid:-translate-y-6 pointer-events-none`}>
          {label}
        </label>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

- Usage component version1

```
<InputLabel
  id="email"
  type="text"
  label="Email"
  required
  value={email}
  onChange={(e: any) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
/>
```

- Usage component version2 (I want to use this)

```
<InputLabel
  id="email"
  type="text"
  label="Email"
  {...register("email", {
    required: "give me your email!",
    minLength: {
      value: 4,
      message: "too short",
    },
    maxLength: {
      value: 15,
      message: "too long",
    },
  })}
/>
```

I want it to work like this:

1. When the focus input box is, the label goes upside and smaller.
2. If I didn't put any typing, the label looks like just a placeholder.
3. I want to use the component with react-hook-form.